PowerBI Dax Function Changes Behavior Based on Column Selection
Using PowerBI, I want to find how much of a product sold within one year of being built. I built a function to evaluate the create date and date purchased.
'DaysSinceProductCreated = DATEDIFF(MAX('Product'[DateCreated]),MAX('Date'[DateValue]),DAY)

Next, I created two functions which called this function to see if it was bought within a year of being built or not.
InYear = 
IF(
    [DaysSinceProductCreated] <=365,
    'Sales'[Amount])

When I have the date columns in the table, it displays like I expect.

But, when I remove the dates from the table, it sums everything up.

How can I keep the formatting of the original table but not have the additional columns?

I don't think we can do that in Power BI.
Here is a workaround for you.
Turn off Text wrap

Then click the column right slide and slowly move to left to hide the columns


